# MVC3 - reference to a separate service project in which module?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, design-patterns

Initial situation:

I would like to build an MVC3 application with a layered architecture. The layers would be the persistence 
layer (repository pattern), service layer and the View layer. I also want to map entities to DTOs in the 
persistence layer, and passing these DTOs to the View.

In the View I would like to apply the MVC pattern by using MVC3 weapp. Now my Question is, in which module, the Controller or the Model should i access (reference to) the service layer. 
I always see references to the service layer in the controller, like this:

```
public class CustomerController
{
 public ViewResult Details( int id )
    {
       CustomerDTO customerDto = MyService.GetCustomerById();
       return View( customerDto );
    }
}
```

Shouldn't I access the service layer in the Model module? If I access my service layer in the controllers, I don't need the Model module at all...?

Comment: Do you need a model layer if you've already got a service layer? If the service is returning it in the exact format you need, there's no need to add extra code. In this case, your service layer is your model.

Comment: Ok, i don't need a model layer in my view, because i got a seperate service layer. But instead, i would create ViewModels for each view.

Answer (score 6):

I always work on the basis that any real work with the service layer is done in the controller.

> If I access my service layer in the controllers, I don't need the Model module at all...?

Incorrect - it is *highly unlikely* that your service types either will have, or even ***should*** have the correct shape and metadata (for example `[Display]` or `[DataType]` attribution) or to make them work correctly with MVC views.  You should have a Model type for all objects that get given to the view, even if they're one-for-one clones of your service types - because then you have a separation between the data that your view and controllers need and your service types.

If you try to bind your views directly to your service types, then you are creating either one of these two scenarios:

- making it harder to change view & controller code because the data being sent to and fro has to conform to service types
- making it harder to change service types because to do so would mean changing every view

The `ViewModel` (or `Model`, depending on your point of view) is your adapter between what's nice for viewing (displaying on a web page) and binding (receiving from a web page) - and it's simply the case that these two things will often drift apart from the *actual* service types used at the business logic level.  Indeed they *should*, because they aim to solve different problems.

Comment: thank you very much, that sounds logical to me. And I should map the data from the service layer (mostly DTOs), to the Model Objects (ViewModel), in the controller as well, right? For this propose, would you recommend to implement a kind of a mapper class?

Comment: Or you *can* use constructors to do that - either copying the physical data, or simply wrapping the instances.  Once you have the separation it's kinda up to you how you map them.  Model classes are dumb in that they don't necessarily talk to the service layer, but when it comes to their relationship to a service *type* I often work on the basis that they are all-knowing so that no other code needs to worry.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether you want to hide MyService from controller.

In your example it's visible. If you had a method on Model of the same name that then delegated to MyService, it wouldn't be.

Advantage of hiding it is you could swap MyService for YourSevice without impacting the View and Controller layers.

As for no model. Where are you defining your DTOs then? Basically MyService would be your model.

You are also operating on the assumption that the DTO for model to controller to view is the same all the way through, even when adding at least one other layer.

I'd think through that assumption if I were you...

Comment: I'm defining my DTO in a separate project, like a common. But i think now it's clear, that i cant use my DTO from the service layer to controller, to the view.